How to debug a Kivy application using PyCharm?
I'm having an issue debugging my Kivy application in PyCharm. I can run the application successfully from the terminal using the following command:
python3 -m src.GUI.brain_boost_app
Everything works as expected. However, when I try to set up a Run/Debug Configuration in PyCharm, I can't get it to work.
Here’s a screenshot of my configuration settings: 
What am I doing wrong? How should I properly configure PyCharm to debug my Kivy application?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Typically the 'script' in the configuration is a python script. And the Script parameters are arguments passed to your script (not to python).
